# Strategy Pattern help needed

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

There exists `interface Algorithm`

There exists `class MathAlgorythm implements Algorithm` `(returns MathResult, which implements Result`)

There exists `class ChemitryAlgorythm implements Algorithm` `(returns ChemitryResult, which implements Result`)

Additionally, there exists a `Context class`, which is used to pass data to these Algos. Data is passed in the following manner:

```
public Result executeStrategy(Data data) {
    return algo.execute(data);
}
```

Suppose I, executeStrategy and get back
    `return MathAlgorithm.execute(data);` I get something of type Result right?

I then execute 
    `return ChemitryAlgorithm.execute(data);` Again i get something Result

**Question:**
Result is an interface. I need to gain access to concrete class implementation as MathResult or ChemistryResult. In other words. Once i get something of type Result, i need to dig deeper and know what class hides behind the interface

I hope this rambling is not too confusing.

Thank you for reading and responding

Comment: It's by the way `algorithm`, with an `i`.

Comment: Strategy is usually employed where different algorithms are used to give (essentially) the same result. So a better examples might be an Optimiser whose different Strategies are SteepestDescents or ConjugateGradients. It's difficult to see Math and Chemistry as alternative Stratgeies. (It would be possible for the Result to have a field for the Strategy Class used if this is all that's required)

Comment: You are correct. The challenge here is exactly that - group different Results under the same umbrella. If both Math.. and Chemistry.. returned the same object, there would have been no problems. I'll google Optimiser now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give `Result` a method like `T get()` which the concrete implementations have to implement, then you don't need to know about the concrete implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question but to know the concrete class of an instance you can use getClass() or alternatively use instanceof to check if it is MathResult etc. Be careful that you dont defeat the whole point of implementing the Result interface.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Result interface is strong enough to satisfy all clients. That's the key so that you don't break polymorphic transparency.

If you really, **really**, **REALLY** need to know the concrete type, you can either use getClass, some sort of unique ID and a getter, or (most preferably) absorb the behavior into an operation of a concrete Result class.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
interface Algorithm<R extends Result, D extends Data> {
  T execute data(D data);
}
```

and then your MathAlgorithm implementation would look like this:

```
class MathAlgorithm implements Algorithm<MathResult, MathData> {
  public MathResult execute(MathData data) {
    // do whatever
    return <instance of MathResult>;
  }
}
```

the usage:

```
MathResult mathResult = new MathAlgorithm().execute(someMathData);
```

Comment: Yes thank you. The issue is that when getting result, i don't want to get MathResult or ChemistryResult. I just want Result if possible. Once i get it, i'd like to see what kind of Result it is and go from there.